# window.requestAnimationFrame woes

Tags: javascript, debugging

I've been alternating between overloading the callstack and getting "parameter 1 is not a function" errors trying to get window.requestAnimationFrame to work right.  The code below gives me a "parameter 1 is not a function" error on trywindow.requestAnimationFrame(gameloop("running")):

```
function gameloop(state,timestamp){
  if(state=="running"){
    elapsed=timestamp-start;
    frame=timestamp-lasttime;  //this is for performance calculations and animations.
    lasttime=timestamp;
    //calculate();
    //quaddetect();
    //raydetect();
    //animate();
  }
  else if(state=="paused"){
    //menu();
    //animate();
  }
}
start=window.performance.now();lasttime=start;
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameloop("running"));
```

And the code below gives me a callstack overflow error(pretty sure i'm just misunderstanding window.requestAnimationFrame for this one):

```
var lasttime=window.performance.now();

function gameloop(state,timestamp){
  if(state=="running"){
    elapsed=timestamp-start;
    frame=timestamp-lasttime;  //this is for performance calculations and animations.
    lasttime=timestamp;
    //calculate();
    //quaddetect();
    //raydetect();
    //animate();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameloop("running"));
  }
  else if(state=="paused"){
    animate();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameloop("running"));
  }
}
start=window.performance.now();
lasttime=start;
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameloop("running"));
```

The question is two part:  why is gameloop("running") not being recognized as a function, and how would I use window.requestAnimationFrame in the correct fashion?

Comment: _“why is gameloop("running") not being recognized as a function”_ – because it is a function _call_, and only the return value of that call is handed over to requestAnimationFrame. What’s expected here instead is a function _reference_ – that would be only `gameloop`, no braces, no parameter. If you have to pass a parameter at this point, encapsulate the call into an anonymous function.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, and for correcting that rather silly mistake.  Makes complete sense after just looking at it (and not throwing anything I can to try to get it to work)...